# How to create a worldfile by bounding box?

Tags: qgis, extents, png

I need to create a worldfile from [Bigmap Application](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bigmap). I've successfully to grab a pack of PNG tiles and the pearl app mosaicking all in one. The BigMap site shows the raster bounding box and util metadata:

Map is 12x12 tiles (3072x3072 px) at zoom 18, aspect 1:1
-43.475647,-22.886297,-43.459167,-22.871114 (l,b,r,t)

This is my local png map | http://goo.gl/oY8vA

This is my pgw configuration:

3072----------X?
0
0
-3072---------Y?
-43.475647----left?
-22.871114----top?

How I create a PGW file  in Quantum GIS or another app?

Jorge Santos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A world file (pgw) consists of

```
width of pixel
rotation about Y axis (nearly always 0)
rotation about X axis (nearly always 0)
negative height of pixel (to make the maths easier)
left edge (in the real world)
top edge (in the real world)
```

so in your case it should be something like:

```
5.364583333333333e-6
0
0
-5.364583333333333e-6
-43.475647
-22.871114
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_file for a full description of the different elements in a world file.

Comment: Thanks iant, but how to calculate the worldfile XY pixel width? My raster shift to down position. Please check this print | http://goo.gl/Tm2Mn | What I done wrong? Jorge Santos

Comment: Line 6 is Y-coordinate of upper left corner (center of pixel)

Comment: Stefan - well spotted, I knew I should have finished my coffee before answering